# In which episode were there two Pikachus?

Tags: pokemon

While adding GIFs to our awesome [*Thrills and Spills* chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7780/thrills-and-spills), I came across an image of two Pikachus and a Togepi:

[image]

At first, I thought it was [Ashachu](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ashachu), but it's not—just a Pikachu with bedhead.

Which episode/canon is this shot from?

Comment: Don't forget: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8396901#8396901

Comment: @Mysticial Funny—that one didn't even cross my mind at the time. Probably because I was in class. I wonder if they're even from the same episode, though; neither Pikachu has the fluffy forehead hair as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Eric: They aren't. That Pikachu was a clone from the first movie. This one is from the anime (Ritchie's IIRC).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's [Sparky](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sparky), [Ritchie](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ritchie)'s Pikachu.

His first appearance was [episode 78](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP078) of the original anime.

Answer (score 3):

The Pikachu's [Sparky](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sparky), trained by [Ritchie](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ritchie).

That particular picture came from the episode when they made a come back to the Johto region, at the end of "Hi Ho Silver Away" and the beginning of "Parent Trapped."